Flutter how to web scrape the result from inserting value into a textfield and click submit?
I am developing mobile app (not web) using flutter.
I am able to scrape data from another webpage however one of the pages allows form input and display the result. How can I insert the value into that page, submit a click and web scrape the result.
I have tried:
    var number = document.querySelector('#number') as InputElement;
    number.value = '1234';
    var submit = document.querySelector('.btn-submit') as ButtonElement;
    submit.click();

It can't recognise InputElement, and if I import 'dart:html' it produced error because I am not using web.
How can insert a textfield value on another website and web scrape the result data from my flutter mobile app? Is this possible?
Thanks
